# 127.0.0.1 refused to connect

Tags: python, html, d3.js, terminal, macros

On command prompt I typed

```
python -m HTTPServer
```

and I got

> Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000

But when I try to access the localhost page it just won't open.

I also tried

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

but still, nothing opens up.

output:

[image: output]

Also, my pc have anaconda installed and I think that it may be hindering with 8000 port. I don't want to uninstall anaconda. How can I use this port or another new port as I m trying to learn D3?

[image]

Comment: Im not able to . when i type python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8001 on commandpromt it says- C:\users\dante\anaconda3\python.exe:No module named SimpleHTTPServer

Answer (score 1):

Using python3, run the following command in the directory of your web assets:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

This should be equivalent to using SimpleHTTPServer in python2.